# Database ID increment with deleted entries

Tags: python, database

I have entries and relationship in my database, for exemple I have a Vehicle database with relationship with drivers. When a drive is affiliate to a vehicle it creates a session in a Vehicle history with the `vehicle_id` and the `driver_id`.

But when I delete this vehicle let's admit it's the `vehicle_id = 4` and it's the last vehicle entry, if I create an other vehicle it will automatically attribute the 4 to the new vehicle, so all the relationship between the old vehicles will now be attribute to the new one... I don't know if I make it clear enough

So do you think I have to keep the vehicle in my database even if it's deleted just to keep the ID count or do you have a particular soluce ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there may ever be an opportunity for the vehicle to be used again, as opposed to deleting it, you could opt to keep the row and implement a status column. When a user "deletes" the vehicle, you could update the status.This could also come in handy for reporting, as you aren't purging data.

Imagine a scenario where you would like to know which drivers have changed cars this month. As a rough example you could do:

`SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE deleted_date BETWEEN xxx AND xxx AND vehicle_status = 'DELETED';`

In your existing queries you could just select everything where the status column != 'DELETED'.

The only downside to this is that you're having to store additional data, but you could implement a system to purge old records from the database after a set period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Set the vehicle id to auto increment, so when you have a new vehicle it will have a new id. Create a new column in the table for vehicle_active and just set it to 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't happen if the ID columns are autoincremented by the database.

If you are doing ID management by yourself (e.g. `new_id = highest_id + 1`), well, you shouldn't!

Also, you should look into how your database system does foreign key references, so you can't delete rows which are referred to by other rows (so this situation can't happen in the first place).

Comment: It happens only if I delete the last entry, so the new entry will take the Id number of the deleted one